# Sharing code in Android Studio IDE

Tags: android, android-studio

Never guessed that it will be so difficult to share code in Android Studio or may be I don't know the right way to do so. I'm expecting to re-use an Android library across multiple projects. But every time, I import this Android library in one project, it makes a copy of it inside the project. Now the problem with this approach is that one library end up in multiple per project copies. 
My question is : How can I share code using Android Studio without duplicating same code in each project. Thanks in advance.

Note: When I say share code, I'm referring to re-using one Android library across multiple projects in ANDROID STUDIO IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a pain sometimes but I use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) in my Android Projects that require the use of the same Library.  The Library Project is stored in its own repository and then the code base is just included by a `git submodule update`.  I know a lot of people complain about submodules but it's the best way I've found so far for working with my Library Projects.  Hope that helps.

Comment: my question is specific to Android studio IDE. Really not asking how can we version control them. Right now, Android Studio IDE ends up making copies of imported module/project.

Answer (score 0):

i recomende using git and github because it's intergrate in android studio then you can go to VCS and -> import into Version control -> share project on github

Comment: my question is specific to Android studio IDE.